# Creating a table and inserting selected streets using plpgsql functions

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to select all streets within 50 meters distance from each address location and store them in a separate table using Postgresql (plpgsql) functions. So far, I have written the following two functions:

- The first function which creates a table sel_streets in database:

  ```
  Create or Replace Function mk_tbl()
  Returns Integer As $$
  Declare
  Begin
  Drop Table if exists sel_streets;
  Create Table sel_street
  (
  id Integer,
  Geom geometry
  );
  Create Index sel_streets_indx
  ON sel_streets Using
  gist (geom);
  Return (1);
  End $$ Language 'plpgsql' volatile;
  ```
- The second fucntion which selects streets within 50 meters and inserts into the table sel_streets

  ```
  Create or Replace Function get_str(ad geometry, st geometry)
  Returns geometry AS $$
  Declare
  Begin
  Insert into sel_streets(geom)
  Select st.geom From ad
  Left Join st On ST_DWithin(ad.geom, st.geom, 50.0);
  Return st;
  End $$
  Language 'plpgsql' volatile;
  ```

I am calling the function by this command:

```
Select mk_tbl(), get_str(ad.geom, st.geom) from ad
Left Join st on st.gid = ad.gid;
```

Here is the screen shot of the output:

[image: output]

I am storing the results into a table because this table will be used in further steps such as use of  ST_Distance and ST_DWithin etc. (which are not shown here). Is there a better way to perform this operation? What I want to do is to create a table in database and then insert the selected streets into this table.  I am looking for some advice (for both functions) to improve this operation (method specifically).

Comment: Why are you storing the results into a table?  What is it that you want to improve?  The performance or the method?

Comment: @kttii: I have edited the question and have added more details to answer your questions here. Precisely, this table will be used in further steps and I need to export the geometry of these selected streets.

Comment: I don't think I would recreate the table every time.  Is your table getting populated with your output or only the last row?  I haven't used that methodology before and my first thought (which could be wrong) is that your statement is dropping and creating the table for every row.

Comment: I am aware that I could have used Create Table() command before start of function syntax. Keeping tables inside a function means I can run this script in SQL window several times (specially when code is in development phase). Please see the output above. I am getting back all 87 rows for corresponding addresses.

Comment: ST_Distance and ST_DWithin could be implemented into get_str().  If you provide more details about how those are being implemented, the answer may be to not store the data into a table but rather just returned as a recordset.  Otherwise, at this point I would just add code to get_str() to check if the table exists first and if not then run mk_tbl() and  remove the mk_tbl() from your statement.

Comment: what is the output of "select count(*) from sel_streets;"

Comment: The count is 260 using the command above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41266/discussion-between-kttii-and-jibran-khan).

Comment: You may be right but if I only return the record set then I can not use sel_streets.geom in next set of functions (because that column wouldn't be existing in DB if I return all rows as a set of record). That's why I stored it separately.